# Prove or find a counterexample: If $f$ is complex and $f\neq 0$ then $\frac{\overline{f} }{f} = \cos(-2Arg(f) ) + i \sin(-2 Arg(f) )$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove or find a counterexample: If $f$ is complex and $f\neq 0$ then $\frac{\overline{f} }{f} = \cos(-2Arg(f) ) + i \sin(-2 Arg(f) )$ where $Arg$ is the principal branch of the argument function, defined in $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$ with range $(-\pi,\pi)$.

My idea is to write $f=r e^{i\theta}$ so that $\frac{\overline{f} }{f}=e^{-2i\theta}$, there $\theta$ is the multivalued argument function. The only thing I am not sure about, is whether or not I can so simply interchange $\theta$ with $Arg$. I am pretty sure that it doesn't really matter, and that indeed the equality holds true, but will be happy to hear any other thoughts about it.

Comment: "With range $(-\pi,\,\pi)$" - what if $f<0$?

Comment: I think the only difference is $\theta$ is allowed to take on values of $Arg(f) + 2\pi n$ and I think $Arg(f)$ is restricted to $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: this is a bit weird as $f$ can definitely take negative values (eg $f(z)=e^z, z=x+i\pi$ so then Arg $f$ is not defined as per OP and the equality makes no sense

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed something I noticed but thought I don't understand some basic aspects of the arumgent function. Anyway, you helped a lot. Thank you!